# CryptoJS PBKDF2 and salt hash method not working

Tags: javascript, hash, salt, cryptojs

I am trying to use PBKDF2 and salt hashing from CryptoJS to store my password. This is the part where I hash the user password from registration:

```
var passwordInput = document.getElementById("txtPasswordInput").value;
var salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128/8);
var key512Bits1000Iterations = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(passwordInput, salt, { keySize: 512/32, iterations: 1000 });

console.log(salt.toString());
console.log(key512Bits1000Iterations.toString());
```

With abcd1234 as password, I managed to store these into my database:

```
Salt: cec16a7e68e0f3e49f729dfd90b0893a
Password: d974b96a494f39aec7f1fa6c495b4783b43e579c070b695...
```

At my login page, I am trying to compute the hash again based on user input to verify the credential:

```
var passwordInput = document.getElementById("txtPassword").value;
// retrieve from firebase
var password = accountData.password;
var salt = accountData.salt;
var key512Bits1000Iterations = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(passwordInput, salt, { keySize: 512/32, iterations: 1000 });
console.log(salt.toString());
console.log(key512Bits1000Iterations.toString());

if(password != key512Bits1000Iterations){
console.log('wrong');
}else{
console.log('correct');
}
```

However, it kept returning me 'wrong'. I printed out the hashsed password and both of them are different though.

Also, after I pressed on the register or login button, the hashing algorithm actually took a while to compute before my browser returns to responsive again. Is the algorithm designed to be slow in computing? Any ideas how to overcome this?

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On login page, the salt needs to be parsed as hex.

Yes, PBKDF2 is designed to be slow.  You can speed it up with fewer iterations  at the cost of security.

Comment: Any reason to parse the salt as hex? Sorry but I am kinda new to cryptography field. Also what is the desired and acceptable range of iteration in this case in terms of speed performance and security purpose?

Comment: @guest176969 1. The use of hex is probably a Javascript way of handling binary data. 2. A reasonable speed is around 100ms of CPU time.

Comment: You serialized the salt to a hex string when you saved it to your database, so now you need to un-serialize it from a hex string.

Comment: @zaph Hmm so is it okay if I reduce the iterations to 500 times? As in what should be the desired amount of iteration

Comment: The commonalty accepted time is around 100ms of CPU time. It is about costing the attacker enough time it is not cost effective to brute force the passwords. It also considers that the attacker will have custom hardware that is substantially faster. The point is that at some level of attack time the cost of electricity is greater than the value of the passwords. The whole scheme is weak but the best we can do and we need to do our best to protect our users.